# System Freeze upon wake-up

Tags: suspend

I am on Natty 11.04.

I have been noticing that upon wake-up from a long inactivity, the screen is not responding to any keystrokes. The mouse is moving though.

This is happening when I am on AC power. The power settings for on AC power are :

- Put computer to sleep ... = Never
- When laptop lid is closed = Suspend (The issue happened when laptop is open and screensaver is ON)
- Put display to sleep when inactive for = 0:15
- Display brightness is 100% and Dim display option is not selected.

Not sure why this is happening. Need your help please to understand the problem and correct it.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being tracked on [Bug #762918](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/762918), there seems to be some tricks that **reduce the probability** of getting screen freezes:

1. Install kernel 2.6.39 or superior
2. Disable sync to v_blank using [compizconfig-setting-manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM)[image: install ccsm] (its on General -> OpenGL)
3. Add `pcie_aspm=force` to the boot options. This should also lower power usage.

   - `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Add `pcie_aspm=force` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
   - Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. Thanks for your suggestion. I am yet to reproduce this issue in 11.10 as yet. So I think this issue is solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of Segio's answer, but I find the discussion more relevant:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/781402

I disabled sync to v_blank and it seems to have fixed it for me.

I would have posted this in a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this one: http://www.multimediaboom.com/fix-screensaver-freezes-in-ubuntu-11-04